# URL redirect on browser language detection

Tags: redirects, multi-language, transcribe

I'm using the Browser Sniff plugin to detect for the browser language on a multilangiage site using Transcribe plugin. It's working for detecting the browser language. I want to redirect users with their browser set to Chinese(zh) to the same url with "zh" as segment_1. So the site currently will display English at www.site.com/page and chinese at www.site.com/zh/page. Now I want to redirect users with their browser set to Chinese from www.site.com/page to www.site.com/zh/page.

I tried this, but it results in a redirect loop:

```
{exp:browser_sniff available_languages="en|zh"}
{if browser_sniff_negotiated_language == "zh"}
     {redirect="zh/{uri_string}"}
{/if}
{/exp:browser_sniff}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop occurs because you're testing again and again and again...

Try this:

```
{exp:browser_sniff available_languages="en|zh"}
    {if browser_sniff_negotiated_language == "zh"}
         {if browser_sniff_negotiated_language != "{segment_1}"}
             {redirect="zh/{uri_string}"}
         {/if}
    {/if}
{/exp:browser_sniff}
```

---

### update

Since Transcribe doesn't count the language for your `segment_1`, use `{exp:transcribe:language_abbreviation}`. If you're already [using this same variable on your template and having parsing issues](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2011/05/expressionengine-and-the-mystery-of-m00o93h7pq09l8x1t49chy01z5j4tt91fgfr/), add a different parameter to one of them or use the [`random` parameter](http://www.emarketsouth.com/add-ons/string-plugin/template-tags/#random-parameter).

```
{exp:browser_sniff available_languages="en|zh"}
    {if browser_sniff_negotiated_language == "zh"}
         {if browser_sniff_negotiated_language != "{exp:transcribe:language_abbreviation random}"}
             {redirect="zh/{uri_string}"}
         {/if}
    {/if}
{/exp:browser_sniff}
```

EECMS template parser replaces all instances of a same variable by a placeholder text to prevent evaluate them more than once. Sometimes, it happens the instances are in different scopes and not all of them are parsed back. So, use the `random` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Robson, unfortunately {segment_1} doesn't detect the language segment in the URL. For example, {segment_1} in this url site.com/zh/engineers returns as "engineers". Transcribe has a variable to return the language letters({exp:transcribe:language_abbreviation}), but when used within the browser_sniff plugin, it returns a string of numbers/letters..."M20o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr" instead of "zh".

Comment: This is because your using `{exp:transcribe:language_abbreviation}` in different parse stages of different scopes. I gonna update my answer.

Comment: BOOOOOMMM!! Adding the random parameter to {exp:transcribe:language_abbreviation random} let it work correctly. I seriously thought I had hit a dead end on this. Thank you so much Robson!